Determine the number of binary strings of length $n$ that do not contain two consecutives $1$s and contain at least three consecutives $0$s
Given binary strings of length $n$ that do not contain two consecutives $1$s, I want to determine by a formula the number of strings that contain at least three consecutives $0$s. How can I do this?
I know how to determine the number of binary strings of length $n$ that do not contain two consecutives $1$s. Basically, this number can be obtained by the Fibonacci sequence:
$$
a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}
$$
With base cases $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1=1$.
The number of binary strings of length $n$ that do not contain two consecutives $1$s correspond to the Fibonacci number $a_{n+2}$.
The problem is that I don't know how to go ahead. I think I have to subtract from this number a certain quantity that I don't know exactly what represents and how to obtain it.

What have you tried so far? It might help adding some context to the question; otherwise, it will likely be closed.

I updated the question

@SamueleBianchi What if you knew the exact number of binary strings that do not contain two consecutive $1$s or two consecutive $0$s?  Would this help?  Lastly, try to write down all such strings of length $5$ (or so).  You should find that there is a very simple way to count these, once you see what they look like.

Sorry i made a mistake. The number of 0's must be at least 3 and not 2. I don't know if your suggestions are still valid.

Personally, I think that this is a tough nut to crack.

@SamueleBianchi i could not understand your question. when you say "contain at least three consecutives $0$s", do you mean that the zeros appear in sequence must have length of at least $3$ such as $1000100000000100000$ or there must be at least one occurence of three consecutive zeros such as $0101001000$

@NotaSalmonFish There must me at least one occurrence of three consecutive zeros.


Given binary strings of length $n$ that do not contain two consecutives $1$s, I want to determine by a formula the number of strings that contain at least three consecutives $0$s. How can I do this?

I am unsure whether the OP's (i.e. original poster's) method, which seems to involve recursion will work here.  My approach is to treat this like a Stars and Bars problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.

Let $~n~$ denote the length of the string.

Let $~k~$ denote the number of 1's in the string. 
This implies that $~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}.$

Let $~f(n,k)~$ denote the number of $~n$-length strings that contain $~k~$ 1's such that there is no occurrence of two consecutive 1's.

Let $~g(n,k)~$ denote the number of $~n$-length strings that contain $~k~$ 1's such that there is no occurrence of two consecutive 1's, and such that there is no occurrence of three consecutive 0's.


Then, the desired computation is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left[ ~f(n,k) - g(n,k) ~\right]. \tag1 $$
So, the entire problem reduces to deriving a closed form formula for both $~f(n,k),~$ and $~g(n,k).$
To simplify the formulas, I will adopt the convention that for any 
$~\displaystyle \binom{a}{b},~$ if $~a < b,~$ then $~\displaystyle \binom{a}{b} = 0.$
As preliminary analysis, consider what happens when $~k = 0.~$
If $~k = 0~$ then

If $~n \leq 2,~$ then there are no satisfying strings, so you can arbitrarily set 
$f(n,0) = 1, ~g(n,0) = 1 \implies f(n,0) - g(n,0) = 0.$

If $~n \geq 3,~$ then there is one satisfying string, so you can arbitrarily set 
$f(n,0) = 1, ~g(n,0) = 0 \implies f(n,0) - g(n,0) = 1.$


For the remainder of the analysis in this answer, it will be assumed that $~k \geq 1.$

$\underline{\text{Closed Form Formula For} ~f(n,k)}$
As an illustration of my idea, assume that $~n = 20,~$ that $~k = 8,~$ and consider the following tableau:
- 1 - - - 1 - - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 -

The distribution of the 1's in the string create $~(k+1) = 9,~$ islands.  Reading the islands from left to right, let $~x_1, ~x_2, ~\cdots, ~x_8, ~x_9~$ denote the respective sizes of these islands.  Then, there will be no occurrence of two consecutive 1's, if and only if each of the variables $~x_2, \cdots, x_8~$ is $~\geq 1.~$
Therefore, $~f(20,8)~$ equals the enumeration of the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 + x_9 = 20 - 8 = 12.$

$x_1, ~x_9 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$x_2, ~x_3, ~\cdots, ~x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$


Since basic Stars and Bars theory requires that each variable have a lower bound of $~0,~$ you need the change of variables $~y_i = x_i - 1 ~: i \in \{2,3,\cdots,8\}.$
Therefore, $~f(20,8)~$ equals the enumeration of the number of solutions to

$x_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_8 + x_9 = 12 - 7 = 5.$

$x_1, ~x_9 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$y_2, ~y_3, ~\cdots, ~y_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$


So, by Stars and Bars theory,
$$f(20,8) = \binom{5 + [9-1]}{9-1} = \binom{13}{8}.$$
For a closed form formula for $~f(n,k),~$ first consider what happens when $~k = 1.$  Then, $~f(n,1)~$ equals the enumeration of the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 = n - 1.$
$x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

So, by Stars and Bars theory,
$$f(n,1) = \binom{[n-1] + [2-1]}{2-1} = \binom{n}{1} = n.$$
The remainder of this section assumes that $~k \geq 2.$ 
Then $~f(n,k)~$ equals the enumeration of the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k + x_{k+1} = n - k.$

$x_1, ~x_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$x_2, ~x_3, ~\cdots, ~x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$


Then, making the change of variables $~y_i = x_i - 1 ~: ~i \in \{2,3,\cdots,k\}~$ the enumeration problem is transformed into

$x_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k + x_{k+1} = (n - k) - (k - 1) = n + 1 - 2k.$

$x_1, ~x_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$y_2, ~y_3, ~\cdots, ~y_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$


So, by Stars and Bars theory, when $~k \geq 2 ~$ :
$$f(n,k) = \binom{[n+1-2k] + [k]}{k} = \binom{n+1-k}{k}. \tag2$$

$\underline{\text{Closed Form Formula For} ~g(n,k)}$
To illustrate the idea, I will first assume that $~n = 20, k = 8.~$ From the previous section, you have that $~\displaystyle f(20,8) = \binom{13}{8}.~$
To compute $~g(20,8),~$ note that a string will not have any occurrence of $~3~$ consecutive 0's, if and only if each of the variables $~x_1, ~\cdots, ~x_9~$ is $~\leq 2.$
So, $~g(20,8)~$ equals the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_8 + x_9 = 20 - 8 = 12.$

$x_1, x_9 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$x_2, \cdots, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

$x_1, \cdots, x_9 \leq 2.$


In order to perform the enumeration, I will follow the model (and syntax) in this answer, which combines Stars and Bars theory with Inclusion-Exclusion theory.
The first step is to adjust the lower bounds, so that $~g(20,8)~$ equals the number of solutions to

$x_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_8 + x_9 = 12 - 7 = 5.$

$x_1, x_9 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$y_2, \cdots, y_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$x_1, x_9 \leq 2.$

$y_2, \cdots, y_8 \leq 1.$


Then,
$$g(20,8) = \sum_{r=0}^9 (-1)^r T_r,$$
where

$T_0 = \displaystyle ~\binom{13}{8}.$

$T_1 = \displaystyle \left[ ~2 \times \binom{10}{8} ~\right] + 
\left[ ~7 \times \binom{11}{8} ~\right].$

To compute $~T_r ~: r \geq 2,~$ you have to break it into $~3~$ cases depending on whether $~0,~1,~$ or $~2~$ of the variables in violation are in $~\{x_1,x_9\}.$  Then $~T_r = T_{r:0} + T_{r:1} + T_{r:2},~$ where:

$\displaystyle T_{r:0} = \binom{2}{0} \times \binom{7}{r} \times \binom{13 - 2r}{8}.$

$\displaystyle T_{r:1} = \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{7}{r-1} \times \binom{13 - 2r - 1}{8}.$

$\displaystyle T_{r:2} = \binom{2}{2} \times \binom{7}{r-2} \times \binom{13 - 2r - 2}{8}.$




Note:
Remember the convention that $~\displaystyle a < b \implies \binom{a}{b} = 0.$
To complete this section, I will first examine what happens when $~k = 1,~$ and then examine what happens when $~k \geq 2.~$
$g(n,1)~$ equals the enumeration of the number of solutions to

$x_1 + x_2 = n - 1.$
$x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
$x_1, x_2 \leq 2.$

So,
$$g(n,1) = \binom{n}{1} - \left[~2 \times \binom{n-3}{1} ~\right] + \binom{n-6}{1}.$$
Using the above formula, and noting that $~a < b \implies \displaystyle \binom{a}{b} = 0,~$ you have that
$$g(3,1), ~g(4,1), ~f(5,1), ~f(6,1), ~g(n \geq 7, 1) = 
~3, ~2, ~1, ~0, ~0, ~~\text{respectively}.$$
The remainder of this section assumes that $~k \geq 2.$ 
Then $~g(n,k)~$ equals the enumeration of the number of solutions to

$x_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k + x_{k+1} = n + 1 - 2k.$

$x_1, ~x_{k+1} \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$y_2, ~y_3, ~\cdots, ~y_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$x_1, ~x_{k+1} \leq 2.~$

$y_2, ~y_3, ~\cdots, ~y_k \leq 1.~$


Generalizing the example of $~g(20,8),~$ you have that
$$g(n,k) = \sum_{r=0}^{k+1} (-1)^r T_r,$$
where

$T_0 = \displaystyle ~\binom{n + 1 - k}{k}.$

$T_1 = \displaystyle \left[ ~2 \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 3}{k} ~\right] + 
\left[ ~\binom{k-1}{1} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2}{k} ~\right].$

For $r \geq 2, ~T_r = T_{r:0} + T_{r:1} + T_{r:2},~$ where:

$\displaystyle T_{r:0} = \binom{2}{0} \times \binom{k-1}{r} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2r}{k}.$

$\displaystyle T_{r:1} = \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{k-1}{r-1} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2r - 1}{k}.$

$\displaystyle T_{r:2} = \binom{2}{2} \times \binom{k-1}{r-2} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2r - 2}{k}.$





$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
All of the formulas in this section follow the convention that 
$a < b \implies \displaystyle \binom{a}{b} = 0.$
The desired computation is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left[ ~f(n,k) - g(n,k) ~\right]. $$
When $~k = 0:~$
$$f(n \leq 2,0) - g(n \leq 2,0) = 0, ~~ f(n \geq 3,0) - g(n \geq 3,0) = 1.$$
When $~k = 1:~$

$f(n,1) = n.$

$g(3,1), ~g(4,1), ~f(5,1), ~f(6,1), ~g(n \geq 7, 1) = 
~3, ~2, ~1, ~0, ~0, ~~\text{respectively}.$


The remainder of this section assumes that $~k \geq 2.$
$$f(n,k) = \binom{[n+1-2k] + [k]}{k} = \binom{n+1-k}{k}.$$
$$g(n,k) = \sum_{r=0}^{k+1} (-1)^r T_r,$$
where

$T_0 = \displaystyle ~\binom{n + 1 - k}{k}.$

$T_1 = \displaystyle \left[ ~2 \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 3}{k} ~\right] + 
\left[ ~\binom{k-1}{1} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2}{k} ~\right].$

For $r \geq 2, ~T_r = T_{r:0} + T_{r:1} + T_{r:2},~$ where:

$\displaystyle T_{r:0} = \binom{2}{0} \times \binom{k-1}{r} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2r}{k}.$

$\displaystyle T_{r:1} = \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{k-1}{r-1} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2r - 1}{k}.$

$\displaystyle T_{r:2} = \binom{2}{2} \times \binom{k-1}{r-2} \times \binom{[n+1-k] - 2r - 2}{k}.$





We can solve this using compositions.
First, since we're looking at binary strings, each string can also be specified by the distances the 1's have from one another, though we have to add two imaginary 1's at start and end of the string.
For example, given $01010010001$ we look at $\color{red}101010010001\color{red}1$, so the distances are $[2,2,3,4,1]$. The first and last number can be 1, but all other have to be $\ge 2$. Furthermore, for the string to be valid, we need at least one number $\ge 4$.
So if we started with a string of length $n$, then our sequence sums to $n+1$.
So we can look at all sequences which sum to $n+1$, $n$ and $n-1$, and which only contain numbers $\ge 2$. For the case $n-1$ we afterwards add a 1 to the left/right, and for the case $n-2$ we add a 1 to the left & right.
Then we do the same, but restrict the numbers to be in $\{2,3\}$ and subtract that. These were the strings which had no two consecutive 1's, but also no three consecutive 0's.

If we fix a $k\inℕ$ and want our sequence to have $k$ elements, then we have now a composition. In first case a composition with a lower bound, in the second case one with lower & upper bound.
To get rid of the lower bound, we just subtract 2 from each element in the sequence, and therefore instead of summing up to $n+1$, we want the elements to sum up to $n+1 -2k$. 
So the number of strings which have no two consecutive 1's and which do not start or end with a 1 is:
$$
\sum_{k\ge 1} C(n+1-2k,k)
$$
, where $C(n,k)$ is the composition of the number $n$ into $k$ parts $\ge 0$.
So in total, the number of strings which have no two consecutive 1's is:
$$
\left(\sum_{k\geq1} C\left(n+1-2k,k\right)\right)+2\left(\sum_{k\geq1} C\left(n-2k,k\right)\right)+\left(\sum_{k\geq1} C\left(n-1-2k,k\right)\right)\tag 1
$$

Now we just need to adapt the above to find the number of strings which have no two consecutive 1's, and which contain only numbers from $\{2,3\}$.
First, we start by removing the lower bound again. Now each composition shall only have numbers from $\{0,1\}$. I.e. if we let $C_{M}(n,k)$ denote the composition of $n$ into $k$ parts where each part is from the set $M$, we have:
$$
\left(\sum_{k\geq1}{C_{\{0,1\}}\left(n+1-2k,k\right)}\right)+2\left(\sum_{k\geq1}{C_{\{0,1\}}\left(n-2k,k\right)}\right)+\left(\sum_{k\geq1}{C_{\{0,1\}}\left(n-1-2k,k\right)}\right)\tag 2
$$

And with that the solution to your problem is $(1)-(2)$. For completeness, note that $C_{\{0,1\}}(n,k):=\binom{k}{n}\delta_{n\ge 0 \land k\ge 0}$.
Furthermore, for big enough $k$ the summands all are 0.

You can handle this problem using generating functions. We will use one of the special case of generating functions called Smirnov words, you can find it  here in page $204-205$.
I will not delve into details of the topic, but give you the solution for your question.
First of all lets calculate the number of bit strings do not contain two consecutive ones and do not restriction over zeros:
$$S(x;1,00...)= \frac{1}{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{1+x} +\frac{\frac{x}{1-x}}{1+\frac{x}{1-x}}\bigg)}$$
$$= \frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}=1+2x+3x^2+5x^3+8x^4+...$$
Here the calculation
Now, we should subtract the cases where the number of bit strings do not contain two consecutive ones and do not contain three consecutive zeros:
$$S(x;1,0+00)= \frac{1}{1-\bigg(\frac{x}{1+x} +\frac{x+x^2}{1+x+x^2}\bigg)}$$
$$= \frac{1+2x+2x^2 +x^3}{1-x^2-x^3}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+...$$
Here the calculation
When we subtract those two sequence, we find the generating function of the binary strings such that it contains at least once three consecutive zeros and do not have any two consecutive ones: $$x^3+3x^4+\color{blue}{6x^5}+12x^6+22x^7+39x^8....$$
The above generating function says that there are six such cases of length $5$ etc.
Here calculation

This seems to start at $n=3$ as 1, 3, 6, 12, 22, 39, 68, 116, 196, 328, 545
with generating function
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0} a(n)x^n = x^3(1+x)^2 ) / ( (x^2+x-1)(x^3+x^2-1)
$$
and recurrence
$$
a(n)= a(n-1) +2a(n-2) -2a(n-4) -a(n-5).
$$
By partial fraction decomposition of the generating function
$$
a(n) = F(n+2) - P(n+8),
$$
where $F$ are the Fibonacci numbers in https://oeis.org/A000045
and $P$ the Padovan numbers https://oeis.org/A000931 .
